# Field Momentum of a Toroid with a point charge at its center

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

I´ve been solving the following problem and I need some guidance. The problem asks to calculate all the components of the field momentum of a circular toroidal coil of mean radius *a* and *N* turns with a small cross section area *A* (which is small compared to *a*). The toroid has corrent *I* flowing in it and there is a point charge *Q* located at its center.

**Atempted Solution**

The electromagnetic momentum field is given by

$$P_{field}=\epsilon_{0}\int_{V} \textbf{E}\times \textbf{B}$$

Calculating the electric field of the point charge we have
$$\textbf{E}=\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}\hat{r}$$

and given that $a>>A$ i wrote the magnetic field of the toroid as

$$\textbf{B}=\frac{\mu_0 NI}{2\pi\epsilon_0 a}\frac{\sin{\theta}}{a}\delta{(\cos{\theta})}\delta{(r-a)}\hat{\phi}$$

performing the integral the result is
$$\epsilon_{0}\int_V \textbf{E}\times \textbf{B}=\epsilon_{0}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{a} (\frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}\hat{r})\times \left(\frac{\mu_0 NI}{2\pi\epsilon_0 a}\frac{\sin{\theta}}{a}\delta{(\cos{\theta})}\delta{(r-a)}\hat{\phi}\right)d^3x=\frac{\mu_0 QNI}{4\pi a^2}\hat{z}$$

however this is incorrect as the expected answer is $$\frac{\mu_0 QNIA}{4\pi a^2}\hat{z}$$ I know that my mistake comes from treating the toroid as a small ring with the current *I* localized in the mean radius *a*, thus the area *A* not appearing after computing the integral. I´ve been told that by taking some aproximations, such as directly asumming the momentum only has a $\hat{z}$ component, this integral can be performed more easily, but i don´t know why i can assume that directly (other than plotting the momentum vector field maybe?).
A way to correct my result that I can think of is to establishing the quantity $\frac{\mu_0 QNI}{4\pi a^2}\hat{z}$ as the momentum field of a ring with radius *a* and the integrating over the area *A* of the toroid. Something like:
$$\int_A P_{ring}=\int \frac{\mu_0 QNI}{4\pi a^2}\hat{z} dA$$
Would this be conceptually correct?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks.

Comment: (1)  If you integrate $\iint \mathbf{B}\cdot d\mathbf{a}$ over a surface of fixed $\phi$, you should get the total magnetic flux passing through the toroid.  So one way to fix it is simply to insert the appropriate factor of $A$ into your expression for $\mathbf{B}$ by fiat, so that the flux equation above holds.  (2) One way to see that the net field momentum points in the $z$-direction is by symmetry.  Our currents & charges are symmetric about the $z$-axis, so the field momentum must be as well.  This means that the total field momentum can't point in the $x$-direction or the $y$-direction.